# how to drilldown for some part of data in ssrs reports 2008

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Hi I have to put drill down option for some part of Data.
My requirement is..I have 50 suppliers and i have to show top 10 suppliers as normal and for remaining 40 suppliers i have to put drill down option in ssrs report 2008

Please help.

Comment: I have to show list of supplers for the Company selected along with  supplied count.

since the company has 50 suppliers the list is going to two pages..so my customer asked to show first top 10 suppliers as normal and for the remaining suppliers he wants me to provide + sign, after clicking + sign i have to show remaining 40 suppliers

Comment: So you want the top 10 suppliers to be shown as 'expanded' and the rest to be shown as 'collapsed'? and it appears you want this as two nodes, rather than a "+" per supplier: i.e. 1-10, 11-n

Answer (score 0):

In the Row Visibility properties of the row on which you've activated the +/- toggle (which is the window where you've activated the "Display can be toggled by ..." option), you can use an expression to show or hide the row.  That means that you'll need to add something to your dataset so that you can decide whether or not a row should be shown by default.

You'll also need to add an expression to the InitialToggleState property of the textbox that's displaying the +/- icon.  Otherwise it will become very confusing.  The icon unfortunately does not automatically reflect the row's visibility.